# References for Yoichi Miyaoka's work around Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

Apparently, Yoichi Miyaoka made a serious attempt to prove FLT in 1988.  See the following question.

[What were the main ideas and gaps in Yoichi Miyaoka's attempted proof (1988) of Fermat's Last Theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213022/what-were-the-main-ideas-and-gaps-in-yoichi-miyaokas-attempted-proof-1988-of)

In that question and [another previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371462/reference-request-for-miyaokas-wrong-proof-of-flt?noredirect=1&lq=1), it was asked whether references for his proof exist. Shockingly, not a single trace of the original mathematical texts seems to be available anymore. This is a sad situation, since it means we cannot learn from his attempt at all.

My question is about the works mentioned in the Barry Cipra article quoted in the above answer:

> **Parshin showed** that the arithmetical version of a certain inequality involving geometric invariants of surfaces—an inequality that **Miyaoka proved** for the geometric case in 1974—would lead…
>
> Miyaoka had "a very interesting idea" to replace the tangent bundle with a "generic" bundle … **Miyaoka has carried** the idea of substituting generic bundles for the tangent bundle back to the original geometric case.

Please see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/213043) for the full quote, I have just bolded the parts I am asking about to avoid duplication of the entire thing. I would like to have references for the work mentioned in the first part, which I am sure experts should be able to provide. (I apologize for my lack of proper background) More optimistically, for the second part it seems that some interesting idea was salvaged and I really hope that there is some reference for it still existing. It would be a real shame if this idea is lost for ever.

Comment: The first part is the famous Miyaoka-Yau inequality: *On the Chern numbers of surfaces of general type*. Invent. Math. 42 (1977), 225–237

Comment: And the "Parshin showed" part is: The Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau inequality for the arithmetical surfaces and its applications. Séminaire de Théorie des Nombres, Paris 1986–87, 299–312, Progr. Math., 75, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1988.